# R - co-locate columns with the same name after merge

Tags: r, merge

**Situation**

I have two data frames, `df1` and `df2`with the same column headings

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(3,2,1)
z <- c(3,2,1)
names <- c("id","val1","val2")

df1 <- data.frame(x, y, z) 
names(df1) <- names

a <- c(1, 2, 3)
b <- c(1, 2, 3)
c <- c(3, 2, 1)

df2 <- data.frame(a, b, c)
names(df2) <- names
```

And am performing a merge

```
#library(dplyr) # not needed for merge
joined_df <- merge(x=df1, y=df2, c("id"),all=TRUE)
```

This gives me the columns in the `joined_df` as `id, val1.x, val2.x, val1.y, val2.y`

**Question**

Is there a way to co-locate the columns that had the same heading in the original data frames, to give the column order in the joined data frame as `id, val1.x, val1.y, val2.x, val2.y`?

Note that in my actual data frame I have 115 columns, so I'd like to stay clear of using `joned_df <- joined_df[, c(1, 2, 4, 3, 5)]` if possible.

Update/Edit: also, I would like to maintain the original order of column headings, so sorting alphabetically is not an option (-on my actual data, I realise it would work with the example I have given).

My desired output is

```
  id val1.x val1.y val2.x val2.y
1  1      3      1      3      3
2  2      2      2      2      2
3  3      1      3      1      1
```

**Update with solution for general case**

The accepted answer solves my issue nicely. 
I've adapted the code slightly here to use the original column names, without having to hard-code them in the `rep` function.

```
#specify columns used in merge
merge_cols <- c("id")

# identify duplicate columns and remove those used in the 'merge'
dup_cols <- names(df1) 
dup_cols <- dup_cols [! dup_cols %in% merge_cols]

# replicate each duplicate column name and append an 'x' and 'y'
dup_cols <- rep(dup_cols, each=2)
var <- c("x", "y") 
newnames <- paste(dup_cols, ".", var, sep = "")

#create new column names and sort the joined df by those names
newnames <- c(merge_cols, newnames)
joined_df <- joined_df[newnames]
```

Comment: The `dplyr` load was superfluous. The `merge` function is in `base`. Could have used `joined_df[c('id', 'val1.x', 'val2.x', 'val1.y', 'val2.y')]`

Comment: well spotted; I was using it for something else and copied it by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

```
numrep <- rep(1:2, each = 2)
numrep

var <- c("x", "y") 
var

newnames <- paste("val", numrep, ".", var, sep = "")

newdf <- cbind(joined_df$id, joined_df[newnames]) 
names(newdf)[1] <- "id"
```

Which should give you the dataframe like this

```
  id val1.x val1.y val2.x val2.y
1  1      3      1      3      3
2  2      2      2      2      2
3  3      1      3      1      1
```

Comment: That's the one. Thanks.